# Smoothest timer interval possible to add values up to 100 within a certain amount of time

Tags: math

In my application (a virtual keyboard), there is a dwell option.
If the user hovers the mouse pointer over a key / button, the button starts filling with color from left to right, and once it's completely changed its color, it is automatically being clicked.

I want to do this using a timer.

At each timer interval / event, the key should be filled a bit more until it reaches an amount of 100.

So at each timer event, I add a certain amount.

The autoclick / dwell time is adjustable.

I'm looking for the formula to fill the key in the smoothest way possible.

The smaller the timer interval, the smoother the color change will look.

The timer however can not tick faster than 25 ms.

Which formula would tell me how many values I need to add each timer event (25 ms)?

Using a timer interval of 25 ms would create the smoothest looking graphical change as the key's color changes slightly and not abruptly.

During 1 second, a timer (with the interval of 25 ms) would fire 40 times.

So if the user wanted a dwell time of 0.30 seconds for a key to click, what would be the formula to determine which value I have to add at each timer event so that the value would be 100 after 0.30 seconds?

A "bad" solution would be to set the timer's interval to 300 ms and choosing an "add value" of 100. In this case, the timer would fire once and set the value to 100. This would work of course, but the graphical change would not be smooth.

Instead, I'm searching for a smoother calculation with more frequent timer events.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by the "smoothest way possible"? Should the key/button be filled at a constant rate?

Comment: @Telescope I have edited my question. "Smoothest way" would mean the most frequent timer interval.

Comment: In that case, I would just increment the amount of color at the next earliest time possible; i.e, by 1 unit every 25 milliseconds. I don't think there's a specialized formula for this problem.

Comment: @Telescope Thank you, I have added something to my question again. Perhaps the formula is not so difficult / special, but right now I don't see it.

Comment: @Telescope Edited my post again with additional information.

Comment: Your question now says that you want to increment the amount of color such that the value would be 100 after 0.30 seconds. 0.3 seconds is equal to 300 milliseconds, or 12 intervals of 25 milliseconds. Thus, you want to increment the value by 100/12 every 25 milliseconds, which is equal to around 8.3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216779/discussion-between-telescope-and-tmighty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smoothest way to animate this sort of thing is not to add a specific amount on each tick.

When the hover starts, you remember the hover `start_time`, and set the timer as fast as you can (25 ms will be fine).  In a browser, use `requestAnimationFrame`

Then at each tick, you get the `current_time` from the system clock, and then calculate:

```
fill_width = full_width * (current_time - start_time) / dwell_time
```

... and fill to the calculated amount.  If the answer is greater than full_width, then you're done and you should stop the timer.

This way, you're always filling the right amount for the current real time, regardless of when the timer fires.  Your animation will be smooth even if the timer is jittery.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just division.  If the dwell time is 300 ms, and your timer ticks every 25 ms, then over the course of the dwell time, the timer ticks `300 / 25 = 12` times.  So the fill value should increase by 1/12 of 100 at each timer tick, which is to say 100/12 = 8.33.

Now if your fill values can only be integers, this will not quite work; and if you round 8.33 to 8 and add 8 at each tick, then the value will only increase by 96 over those 300 ms.  So what you should do instead is to keep track of how many ticks have taken place so far (call it `t`), and at each tick, set the value to `100*t/12`, rounded to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

Formula for determining amount to add for each tick (keep timer at 25ms for most frequent updates):

```
TICKS = DWELL_TIME / 0.025 (ms)
VALUE_PER_TICK = 100 / TICKS
```

Which can be simplified by combining division:

```
VALUE_PER_TICK = 100.0 / ( DWELL_TIME / 0.025 )
```

For your example (DWELL_TIME = 0.3):

TICKS = 12

VALUE_PER_TICK = 8.33

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the smoothest way possible (by your own definition) to fill the key with color, we should increment the value counter as often as possible.

Because you wanted to increment `value` to 100 in `0.3` seconds, and each increment can happen every `25` milliseconds, we can calculate the increment value as such:

`0.3` seconds is equal to `300` milliseconds, or `12` intervals of `25` milliseconds. Thus, you want to increment `value` to 100 throughout `12` intervals.

In other words, with a constant increment rate, you want to increment value by `100/12` every step, or around `8.33` units.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While your calculation is perfectly fine, the answer by Matt Timmermans is even smoother, so I will accept his answer, ok?